# WordPress rewrite for single posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress installation where I have my blog section under the Menu news - once clicked I go to the url mysite.com/news/ and all blog entries are listed.

Once I click on a single news item though the /news/ URL gets removed and ends up on mysite.com/2013/01/02/articlename/

Is there a way to add a rewrite rule or 301 redirect that it leads to the url  mysite.com/news/2013/01/02/articlename/ ?

Some expert advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the wordpress has a default permalink format like:http://xxx.com/?p=111,the 111 is a postId.if you change your permalink format,you can redirect your old links to the default style,and when users goto the default link,wordpress will jump to your new link auto.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I thought these permalink settings would affect the entire site , instead it turns out they just do what I was looking for. Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Would there eventually also be a 301 redirect solution?

Comment: tell me your old permalink format and the new ,i try to redirect it

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply: mysite.com/2013/01/02/articlename/ <- old / mysite.com/news/2013/01/02/articlename/ <- new

Comment: i test the worked .htacess is: `RewriteRule ^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/\S*/)$ /news/$1` ,and here is a .htacess test site:http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ ,you can input your old links and the redirect rule to check it, if the test is ok but it's not work in your site,please clear your cache before

Comment: Thank you LIXer , that's very kind - will this be a 301 redirect?